# How to build tenssorflow op with bazel with additional include directories

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I got tensorflow binaries (already compiled)
I have added to tensorflow source:
`tensorflow\core\user_ops\icp_op_kernel.cc` - contains:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/vid2depth/ops/icp_op_kernel.cc
`tensorflow\core\user_ops\BUILD` - contains:

```
load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_custom_op_library")

tf_custom_op_library(
    name = "icp_op_kernel.so",
    srcs = ["icp_op_kernel.cc"],
)
```

I am trying to build with:

```
bazel build --config opt //tensorflow/core/user_ops:icp_op_kernel.so
```

And I get:

```
tensorflow/core/user_ops/icp_op_kernel.cc(16): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pcl/point_types.h': No such file or directory
```

Because bazel don't know where the pcl include files are.
I have installed pcl and the include directory is in:

```
C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6
```

How do I tell bazel to also include this directory?

Also I will probably need to add `C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\lib` to the link, How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `bazel` for building ops if it fails.

I have implemented customized ops both in CPU and GPU, and basically follow the  two Tensorflow tutorials.

For CPU ops, follow Tensorflow tutorial on [Build the op library](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op#build_the_op_library):

```
TF_CFLAGS=( $(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(" ".join(tf.sysconfig.get_compile_flags()))') )
TF_LFLAGS=( $(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(" ".join(tf.sysconfig.get_link_flags()))') )
g++ -std=c++11 -shared zero_out.cc -o zero_out.so -fPIC ${TF_CFLAGS[@]} ${TF_LFLAGS[@]} -O2
```

Note on `gcc` version `>=5`: gcc uses the new `C++ ABI` since version 5. The binary pip packages available on the TensorFlow website are built with gcc4 that uses the older ABI. If you compile your op library with `gcc>=5`, add `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` to the command line to make the library compatible with the older abi.

For GPU ops, check the current official GPU ops building instructions on [Tensorflow adding GPU op support](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op#gpu_support)

```
nvcc -std=c++11 -c -o cuda_op_kernel.cu.o cuda_op_kernel.cu.cc \
  ${TF_CFLAGS[@]} -D GOOGLE_CUDA=1 -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC

g++ -std=c++11 -shared -o cuda_op_kernel.so cuda_op_kernel.cc \
  cuda_op_kernel.cu.o ${TF_CFLAGS[@]} -fPIC -lcudart ${TF_LFLAGS[@]}
```

As it says, Note that if your CUDA libraries are not installed in `/usr/local/lib64`, you'll need to specify the path explicitly in the second (g++) command above. For example, add `-L /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/` if your CUDA is installed in `/usr/local/cuda-8.0`.

Also, Note in some linux settings, additional options to nvcc compiling step are needed. Add `-D_MWAITXINTRIN_H_INCLUDED` to the nvcc command line to avoid errors from `mwaitxintrin.h`.

Comment: I am actually trying to build it on windows, I will try to translate what you proposed.

Comment: The following fails:
`nvcc -std=c++11 -c -o cuda_op_kernel.cu.o cuda_op_kernel.cu.cc -IC:\Users\dorp\Desktop\tensorflow-1.11.0 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -D GOOGLE_CUDA=1 -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC`
Error:
`C:/Users/dorp/Desktop/tensorflow-1.11.0\third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor': No such file or directory`